# PayPal REST API: "Client Authentication failed" in sandbox mode

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am currently trying to implement the paypal api to get the details of an order, but it shows me the following error:

**Uncaught PayPalHttp\HttpException: {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"Client Authentication failed"} in vendor/paypal/paypalhttp/lib/PayPalHttp/HttpClient.php on line 215**

I am using the data that paypal gives me of the client id and the secret that is checked in: https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications/ following the official documentation, after i set up my server to make calls to PayPal, im currently following this guide: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/get-transaction/

I've been trying to find the solution for two days without much success, do you know why paypal marks this error?

As a note, I am still in sandbox (the client and the secret are from the sandbox too) and I am using the default application created by paypal, does it have something to do with it?

Comment: Provide more details, including your request+response to get the access token, and the full request+response (including headers with the access token) of the API call that is failing.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the request for an access token is failing, but we cannot comment specifically without seeing a full request+response log added to your question's details.

Ensure you are connecting to api(-m).sandbox.paypal.com with HTTP basic authentication  ("Authentication: Basic ..." header) that has a base64 encoded `clientid:secret` of a Sandbox REST API app, and that the POST data is `grant_type=client_credentials`

Documentation: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/overview/#get-credentials